# Who were the murder victims in "All Light Will End"?

Tags: plot-explanation, all-light-will-end

### This question is based on a major spoiler of the film, you've been warned.

In the movie [*All Light Will End* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6023386/) there are several scenes that indicate there are several murders occurring in a small town. Two severed hands are found early in the film and the police are investigating.

The primary story however follows a woman who grew up in the small town who left home years ago and hasn't been back. Her father invites her to come back for her brother's graduation and she eventually decides to go because her friends insist.

The big reveal of the film is that the main girl is the murderer and that she murdered her mother who psychologically abused her. But what is never explained is who the other victims were and how did she kill them if she's never been back to her home town? Who did the severed hands belong to?